# Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'tmp_field_2' at row 1

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, timestamp

I'm trying to run the following query:

```sql
INSERT INTO `user_domain_rating_days`
            (
                        `user_domain_rating_id`,
                        `start`,
                        `user_id`,
                        `domain_id`,
                        `modified_count`,
                        `modified_count_diff`,
                        `rating`,
                        `rating_diff`,
                        `transformed_rating`,
                        `transformed_rating_diff`,
                        `q_score`,
                        `q_score_diff`,
                        `timestamp_diff`,
                        `session_count`,
                        `last_full_session`
            )
SELECT    MAX(`latest`.`user_domain_rating_id`),
          :date,
          MAX(`latest`.`user_id`),
          MAX(`latest`.`domain_id`),
          @modified_count := MAX(`latest`.`modified_count`),
          @modified_count_diff := SUM(`group_by`.`modified_count_diff`),
          @rating := MAX(`latest`.`rating`),
          @rating_diff := SUM(`group_by`.`rating_diff`),
          @transformed_rating := MAX(`latest`.`transformed_rating`),
          @transformed_rating_diff := SUM(`group_by`.`transformed_rating_diff`),
          @q_score := MAX(`latest`.`q_score`),
          @q_score_diff := SUM(`group_by`.`q_score_diff`),
          @timestamp_diff := SUM(`group_by`.`timestamp_diff`),
          @session_count := MAX(`latest`.`session_count`),
          @last_full_session := MAX(`latest`.`last_full_session`)
FROM      `user_domain_rating_hours` AS `group_by`
LEFT JOIN
          (
                 SELECT *
                 FROM   `user_domain_rating_hours`
                 WHERE  `id` IN
                        (
                                 SELECT   MAX(`id`)
                                 FROM     `user_domain_rating_hours`
                                 WHERE    `start` >= :date
                                 AND      `start` < DATE_ADD(DATE(:date), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                 GROUP BY `user_id`,
                                          `domain_id` ) ) AS `latest`
ON        `group_by`.`user_id` = `latest`.`user_id`
AND       `group_by`.`domain_id` = `latest`.`domain_id`
WHERE     1
AND       NOW() > DATE_ADD(DATE(:date), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND       `group_by`.`start` >= :date
AND       `group_by`.`start` < DATE_ADD(DATE(:date), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY  `group_by`.`user_id`,
          `group_by`.`domain_id` LOCK IN SHARE MODE
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE `user_domain_rating_days`.`id` = `user_domain_rating_days`.`id` ;
```

which worked fine when `last_full_session` was not present yet. This new column is created like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `user_domain_rating_days` ADD `last_full_session` timestamp NULL AFTER `session_count`;
```

We are running mysql (Percona 5.7 to be specific) with the following `sql_mode`: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`. When I remove `NO_ZERO_DATE` from the `sql_mode`, the query runs fine (not even `0000-00-00 00:00:00` values in the destination table).

When I only run the `SELECT` part of the query it also runs fine. `@last_full_session := MAX(`latest`.`last_full_session`)` is `NULL` which is supported by the destination table. However in combination with the `INSERT INTO` something changes, `NULL` seems to be converted to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

What am I missing?

```
mysql> show variables like 'explicit_defaults_for_timestamp';
+---------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                   | Value |
+---------------------------------+-------+
| explicit_defaults_for_timestamp | OFF   |
+---------------------------------+-------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE `user_domain_rating_days` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_domain_rating_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `start` date NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `domain_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `modified_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `modified_count_diff` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rating` double NOT NULL,
  `rating_diff` double NOT NULL,
  `transformed_rating` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `transformed_rating_diff` double NOT NULL,
  `q_score` smallint(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `q_score_diff` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp_diff` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `session_count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_full_session` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_domain_day` (`user_id`,`domain_id`,`start`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_domain_rating_id_day` (`user_domain_rating_id`,`start`),
  KEY `domain_id` (`domain_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_domain_rating_days_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_domain_rating_days_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`domain_id`) REFERENCES `domains` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_domain_rating_days_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`user_domain_rating_id`) REFERENCES `user_domain_ratings` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

```
mysql> SELECT version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.24-27 |
+-----------+
```

```
# mysqld --version
mysqld  Ver 5.7.24-27 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (Percona Server (GPL), Release '27', Revision 'bd42700')
```

Comment: Discussion **[moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89665/discussion-between-ypercube-and-tersmitten)**.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug, so I suggest you file a bug report to either Percona or MySQL, with a smaller exammple that reproduces the error (keep only the problematic column).

In the mean time, a suggestion that may remove the error:

There are two `GROUP BY` operations in the query one performed in the `latest` subquery, to find the latest timestamps per group and another, performed in the main query, to get SUMs of various columns from the main table.

This requires the use of an aggregate (`MAX`) for the results coming from the `latest` subquery - although we have only 1 row per group from that. In order to avoid that (second `GROUP BY` applied to `latest`), we can move that (second GROUP BY) to another subquery and then join `latest`.

This would allow us to have no GROUP BY in the main query (and as I suspect get rid of the error which is somehow caused by applying `MAX()` to `NULL` valued timestamps that come from the `latest` subquery). The rewritten query:

**`-- INSERT part (unchanged)`**

```
INSERT INTO `user_domain_rating_days`
            (
                        `user_domain_rating_id`,
                        `start`,
                        `user_id`,
                        `domain_id`,
                        `modified_count`,
                        `modified_count_diff`,
                        `rating`,
                        `rating_diff`,
                        `transformed_rating`,
                        `transformed_rating_diff`,
                        `q_score`,
                        `q_score_diff`,
                        `timestamp_diff`,
                        `session_count`,
                        `last_full_session`
            )
```

**`-- main query SELECT (aggregates removed)`**

```
SELECT    `latest`.`user_domain_rating_id`,
          :date,
          `latest`.`user_id`,
          `latest`.`domain_id`,
          @modified_count := `latest`.`modified_count`,
          @modified_count_diff := `group_by`.`modified_count_diff`,
          @rating := `latest`.`rating`,
          @rating_diff := `group_by`.`rating_diff`,
          @transformed_rating := `latest`.`transformed_rating`,
          @transformed_rating_diff := `group_by`.`transformed_rating_diff`,
          @q_score := `latest`.`q_score`,
          @q_score_diff := `group_by`.`q_score_diff`,
          @timestamp_diff := `group_by`.`timestamp_diff`,
          @session_count := `latest`.`session_count`,
          @last_full_session := `latest`.`last_full_session`
FROM
```

**`-- group_by subquery`**

```
    (
    SELECT    user_id,
              domain_id,
              SUM(g.`modified_count_diff`) AS modified_count_diff,
              SUM(g.`rating_diff`) AS rating_diff,
              SUM(g.`transformed_rating_diff`) AS transformed_rating_diff,
              SUM(g.`q_score_diff`) AS q_score_diff,
              SUM(g.`timestamp_diff`) AS timestamp_diff,
    FROM      `user_domain_rating_hours` AS g
    WHERE     1
    AND       NOW() > DATE_ADD(DATE(:date), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND       g.`start` >= :date
    AND       g.`start` < DATE_ADD(DATE(:date), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    GROUP BY  g.`user_id`,
              g.`domain_id` LOCK IN SHARE MODE
    ) AS `group_by`
```

**`-- latest subquery (unchanged)`**

```
LEFT JOIN
          (
                 SELECT *
                 FROM   `user_domain_rating_hours`
                 WHERE  `id` IN
                        (
                                 SELECT   MAX(`id`)
                                 FROM     `user_domain_rating_hours`
                                 WHERE    `start` >= :date
                                 AND      `start` < DATE_ADD(DATE(:date), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                 GROUP BY `user_id`,
                                          `domain_id` ) ) AS `latest`
ON        `group_by`.`user_id` = `latest`.`user_id`
AND       `group_by`.`domain_id` = `latest`.`domain_id`
```

**`-- GROUP BY removed`**

```
-- GROUP BY ...
```

**`-- unchanged part`**

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE `user_domain_rating_days`.`id` = `user_domain_rating_days`.`id` ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and worked around it by coalescing the aggregated column to a default value I can handle later. In my case, I used the earliest valid timestamp value.

```
max(coalesce(left_joined_table.timestamp_column, '1970-01-01 00:00:01'))
```